# Callbacks from autobahn WebSocketClientProtocol to another object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, autobahn

Firstly, there is an `IO` class, which on `__init__` is passed the asyncio loop object (`io = IO(loop)`), created earlier in the main class. `IO` class then at some point initializes the `Socket` class by doing `self.socket = Socket(self)`, so that the socket object has a backwards access. Later, the `Socket` class initializes `Websocket` class which is a subclass of `Transport`

```
class Websocket(Transport):

    name = 'websocket'

    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket

    def open(self):
        url = self.prepareUrl()

        factory = WebSocketClientFactory(url, debug = False)
        factory.protocol = Protocol

        websocket = self.socket.loop.create_connection(factory, host=self.socket.io.options.host, port=self.socket.options.port)

        self.socket.io.loop.run_until_complete(websocket)

    def onOpen(self):
        print('print me please!')
```

So, socket object calls `self.transport.open()` (where `self.transport = Websocket(self)`), which creates autobahn factory, creates asyncio connection by doing `self.socket.loop.create_connection()` and then adds the coro future to the loop by executing `run_until_complete()`.

Now, this is where the problem starts:
autobahn factory requires a class, which must inherit from `autobahn.asyncio.websocket.WebSocketClientProtocol`

My class `Protocol(WebSocketClientProtocol)` has the usual:

```
class Protocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onOpen(self):
        print('socket opened!')
```

This works perfectly fine, the `print('socket opened!')` does print the string and my server also says the connection is open.

The question:
from the Protocol() class, when the onOpen() callback is called by autobahn, how can I make this method call the transport.onOpen() method and do `print('print me please!')`?

Comment: The only solution I have found so far is to have a reference to socket object within the loop object, so that from `Protocol.onOpen()` coroutine I am able to do something like `self.factory.loop.socket.transport.onOpen()`. To make the things a bit more pretty I can pass the loop object around as a baseline, which would have a structure like `loop.io.socket.transport`. But again, was the loop object really intended to hold third-party references within itself? To me this looks a bit too hacky...

Comment: In cpp I've used signals2 for similar purpose and for some reason I was trying to search the term "signals" for python this time...and of course haven't found anything relevant... Now, I'm looking into PyDispatcher and others. If no one posts before I find a good enough solution, I'll self-answer the q. I think I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I fixed it! Easily done with PyDispatch module.

Here is my solution:

```
import asyncio
from pydispatch import dispatcher
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory

from ..transport import Transport

class Websocket(Transport):

    name = 'websocket'

    def __init__(self, socket):
        self.socket = socket

    def open(self):
        url = self.prepareUrl()

        factory = WebSocketClientFactory(url, debug = False)
        factory.protocol = Protocol

        websocket = self.socket.loop.create_connection(factory, host=self.socket.io.options.host, port=self.socket.options.port)

        dispatcher.connect(self.onOpen, signal='open', sender=dispatcher.Anonymous)

        self.socket.io.loop.run_until_complete(websocket)

    def onOpen(self):
        print('print me please!')


class Protocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onOpen(self):
        dispatcher.send(signal='open')
```

**UPDATE**

I've got another, IMO better solution to this. This one is not using PyDispatch. Since there is a callback when an asyncio task finishes, which returns the user-defined protocol object (which inherits from WebSocketClientProtocol), we can use that to link the two objects together:

```
import asyncio
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory

from ..transport import Transport

class Protocol(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = None
        super().__init__()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onConnect(self, response):
        pass # connect handeled when SocketIO 'connect' packet is received

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onOpen(self):
        self.ws.onOpen()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        self.ws.onMessage(payload=payload, isBinary=isBinary)

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        if not wasClean:
            self.ws.onError(code=code, reason=reason)

        self.ws.onClose()           

class Websocket(Transport):

    name = 'websocket'

    def __init__(self, socket, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(socket)

        loop = kwargs.pop('loop', None)
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        self.transport = None
        self.protocol = None

        self.ready = True

    def open(self):
        url = self.prepareUrl()
        if bool(self.socket.options.query):
            url = '{0}?{1}'.format(url, self.socket.options.query)

        factory = WebSocketClientFactory(url=url, headers=self.socket.options.headers)
        factory.protocol = Protocol

        coro = self.loop.create_connection(factory, host=self.socket.options.host, port=self.socket.options.port, ssl=self.socket.options.secure)

        task = self.loop.create_task(coro)
        task.add_done_callback(self.onWebSocketInit)

    def onWebSocketInit(self, future):
        try:
            self.transport, self.protocol = future.result()
            self.protocol.ws = self
        except Exception:
            self.onClose()

    def send(self, data):
        self.protocol.sendMessage(payload=data.encode('utf-8'), isBinary=False)
        return self

    def close(self):
        if self.isOpen:
            self.protocol.sendClose()
        return self

    def onOpen(self):
        super().onOpen()
        self.socket.setBuffer(False)

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        if not isBinary:
            self.onData(payload.decode('utf-8'))
        else:
            self.onError('Message arrived in binary')

    def onClose(self):
        super().onClose()
        self.socket.setBuffer(True)

    def onError(self, code, reason):
        self.socket.onError(reason)
```